# How to upload and read PDF files in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, file-upload, pypdf

I am trying to create a simple `django` application which takes some `PDF` files from user and then read its contents. So far I have written the code as mentioned below, But it doesn't seem to work. It's producing an error at this line `PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(filename))`

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TemporaryUploadedFile

**index.html**

```
<input type="file" name="fupload" multiple>
```

**view.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.FILES.getlist('fupload')

        pdf_data = []
        for filename in files:
            read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(filename))
            page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
            page_content = page.extractText()
            pdf_data.append(page_content)
```

Can any body tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably need to use `open(filename.temporary_file_path())`. [See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile.temporary_file_path)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your views.py to this:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:

        pdfFileObj = request.FILES['myfile'].read() 
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(pdfFileObj))
        NumPages = pdfReader.numPages
        i = 0
        content = []
        while (i<NumPages):
            text = pdfReader.getPage(i)
            content.append(text.extractText())
            i +=1
```